# Converting human number string to float in ruby or rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I searched for a while for a ruby or rails method that I can call to convert a simple string like `1,000.53` into a float value but I couldn't.

All I could see is number_to_human which does the reverse of what I want. Is there anything available for my use case or am I alone (which I dont think). Also all I want is a simple conversion as above with commas and dot. No fancy currency or other any other notation conversion needed.

Thanks

EDIT

`'1,000.5'.gsub(/,/, '').to_f` works but I am looking for an already available method in ruby or rails. Or a better alternative to my solution with gsub.

Comment: You can do to_f method to convert a string to a float number. But in this case the string contains a comma character, so you have to delete it first.

str = "1,000.53"
str.delete(",").to_f

This will give you the proper float number.

Comment: I don't know how this question was marked as repeated.

a) The question that it points only handles numbers on an english locale
b) The solution provided would now match things that are not numbers into numbers

Answer (score 13):

First, remove all chars from the string that are not a digit or the separator (`.` in your example). Then call `to_f` on the sanitized string:

```
'1,000.53'.gsub(/[^\d.]/, '').to_f #=> 1000.53
```

Answer (score -6):

`to_f` might work

Try `"your_string".to_f`

Comment: nope. it wont. '1,000'.to_f #=> 1.0

Comment: Welcome to SO, Laura. `'1,000.53'.to_f` would return 1.0 because of how the method does coercions. Hence the OP's question. You can always edit your answer, or delete it if it attracts too many downvotes.